# Error while plotting a function, having an integration in equation

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I am trying to plot a function which also includes a definite integration but I am getting an error (invalid integration variable or limit(s)
Here is the code which I am trying

```
    w = 1.26*10^8;
    k = 1.38*10^-23;
dynamicImag[T_?NumericQ, s_?NumericQ, d_?NumericQ, A_?NumericQ, 
  t_?NumericQ] := A*(1 - NIntegrate[(w*t*(((1/(Sqrt[2*Pi]*s*H))*Exp[(-(Log[(H/d)])^2/(2*s^2))])))/((1 + (w^2*t^2*Exp[((2*H)/(k*T))]))), {H, 0, 6.0*10^-22}])
   PlotImag = Plot[dynamicImag[T, 0.24, 8*10^-23, 1*10^-4, 1*10^-12], {T, 0, 1.6}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Check the units of $k$.  They should be the same as the units of $H/T$. The plot of `f[H,s,d]` is non-zero for values of $H\approx d = 8$ and you have $k$ 23 orders of magnitude different.  It may be helpful to plot $f$, then plot $1/(1+\omega^2 \tau^2)$, then plot $f / (1+\omega^2 \tau^2)$ before putting it into `NIntegrate`.

Comment: @LouisB I modified the code incorporating your suggestions, But I am still getting error which I do not understand  "NIntegrate::izero: Integral and error estimates are 0 on all integration subregions. Try increasing the value of the MinRecursion option. If value of integral may be 0, specify a finite value for the AccuracyGoal option."

Comment: Changing the plot limits to `{T, 0.01, 1.6}` makes the "NIntegrate:: ..." error go away for me.

Comment: Simply specify AccuracyGoal -> 12 in the integration.